# Error en lista ligada en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo una lista ligada en C de datos enteros que se guardan en ella hasta que se presiona Enter.
El problema está en que el último elemento que guarda es basura, pues guarda una dirección de memoria dinámica y aún no encuentro el error.

Aquí está mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
   int dato;
   struct nodo *siguiente;
}lista;

int main(void)
{
int dato;
lista *list = (lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo)), *aux = list;

printf("Ingresa datos enteros (enter para terminar): ");
do
{
    scanf("%d", &dato);
    list->dato = dato;
    list->siguiente = (lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    list = list->siguiente;

}while(getchar() != 10);
list->siguiente = NULL;

while(aux != NULL)
{
    printf("%d   %d\n", aux, aux->dato);
    aux = aux->siguiente;
}

return 0;
 }
```

Y esta es una imagen del problema al que me refiero[image: El último dato es al que me refiero que se guarda como basura]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en la lógica interna que estas usando. Analicemos con detalle tu bucle `do ... while`:

```
do
{
  scanf( "%d", &dato );
  list->dato = dato;
  list->siguiente = (lista *)malloc( sizeof( struct nodo ) );
  list = list->siguiente;   
}while( getchar( ) != 10 );
list->siguiente = NULL;
```

1. Lees el dato del teclado.
2. Lo guardas en el nodo actual.
3. Creas un nuevo nodo vacío (sin inicializar).
4. Avanzas tu puntero a ese nuevo nodo que has creado.
5. Si el usuario pulsa *ENTER*, terminas el bucle.

Fíjate bien. Terminas el bucle **dejando el último nodo sin inicializar**.

Una posible solución sería utilizar una variable auxiliar, para no perder de vista el nodo anterior. Como verás, también he cambiado el modo de terminar la introducción de datos: en mi sistema, tu solución con `getchar( )` no funciona; ahora, hay que introducir **una letra** para terminar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo {
  int dato;
  struct nodo *siguiente;
}lista;

int main( void ) {
  int dato;
  lista *list = malloc( sizeof( lista ) );
  lista *aux = list;
  lista *prev = list;

  printf( "Ingresa datos enteros (una letra para terminar):\n");

  while( scanf( "%d", &dato ) ) {
    list->dato = dato;
    prev = list;
    list->siguiente = malloc( sizeof( lista ) );
    list = list->siguiente;
  };

  if( aux == list ) {
    printf( "¡ La lista está vacía !\n" );
    free( aux );
    aux = NULL;
  } else {
    free( prev->siguiente );
    prev->siguiente = NULL;
  }

  while( aux ) {
    printf( "%p: %d\n", aux, aux->dato );
    aux = aux->siguiente;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Hay una parte extra, justo después del `while( )`, que es la que se encarga de controlar la *corrección* de la lista: si está vacía, lo indica, y si no lo está, elimina el último nodo y coloca adecuadamente el puntero `siguiente` en el **penúltimo** nodo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo pude probar y es verdad, sólo fue un error de lógica que se debía corregir.. Gracias y saludos :)